# atualizar input com jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Em cada linha da tabela eu tenho um input, eu preciso mudar o valor do input com o valor da posição da linha. Como posso fazer isso?

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('tbody').sortable({
            axis: 'y',
            containment: 'parent',
            change: function(){ 
console.log("change"); 
              $.each($(".tab_dados tbody>tr"), function(indice, obj){
                 $(this).find($("td>input[type=text]")).val(indice + 1);
              });
        }
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<table class="tab_dados">
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th style="width: 30px;"></th>
    <th>CÓDIGO</th>
    <th>NOME</th>
    <th>input</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>25</td>
    <td>HUGO</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="id25" value="1"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>26</td>
    <td>bruno</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="id26" value="2"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>27</td>
    <td>rafael</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="id27" value="3"></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
        $('tbody').sortable({
            axis: 'y',
            containment: 'parent',
            animation: 200,
            stop: function(){  
                  $.each($(".tab_dados tbody>tr"), function(indice, obj){
                     $(this).find($("input[type=text]")).val(indice + 1);
                  });
            }
        });
    });
```

No evento: `stop` do sortable pode verificar todas as linhas.

Dê uma olhadinha na documentação pra o que tu vai precisar daqui em diante: [Sortable](https://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/)

Comment: não entendi muito bem. poderia me explicar melhor.

Comment: Ficou mais claro, @HugoBorges?

Comment: Eu tinha tentando assim e não deu certo. Eu até editei a pergunta com a sua resposta. Não gerou log de erros tbm.

Comment: Se tu depurar o js, pára na função de change?

Comment: A função de change está sendo executada, coloquei um log para poder verificar. A unida coisa que não ocorre é a alteração dos valores do input. Sendo que eles sempre tem que estar em ordem. Ou seja o 1º input sempre vai ser 1, o 2º sempre vai ser 2 e etc...

Comment: Só pra testarmos, coloca o type="text" nos inpt. E também altera aqui: $(this).find($("td>input[type=text]")).val(indice + 1);

Comment: Pronto alterei, coloquei o log para vc ver tbm. Continua não funcionando.

Comment: Prontinho. Só dar uma olhadinha na documentação pra o que tu vai precisar daqui em diante. (=

Comment: deu certo, muito obrigado